# Need help combining jquery serialize with not or filter

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I'm trying to serialize a form and exclude certain elements. but nothing is working.  here are some examples.

```
$.post("process.php", $("#featured-form").filter("select").serialize(), function(res) {
$.post("process.php", $("#featured-form").filter(".exclude").serialize(), function(res) {
```

does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) filters out the elements that *don't* match the specified selector. Since you seem to want the opposite behavior, you probably should use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) instead.

Then, you have to select the form elements in order to filter them, not the form itself. The following should do what you want:

```
$("#featured-form :input").not("select, .exclude").serialize();
```